# Create site template with PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I would like to save a few SharePoint Online sites as template for future use with PowerShell. How can I do this? I found code snippets for 2013 but they do not seem to work, I'm missing methods, cannot retrieve the web object (no `Get-SPWeb`), thus no `.SaveAsTemplate`. What are my options? I have 100+ different sites to save.

Update:
All my different sites that I want to make template of, are under a site collection.
This is how far I am with the PnP Powershell:

```
$WebURL = "myroot"
Connect-PnPOnline –Url $WebURL -Credentials $credential
foreach ($web in Get-PnPSubWebs -Recurse) {
$url = $web.url
Connect-PnPOnline –Url $web.url –Credentials $credential
$filename = $url -replace $WebURL, "" -replace "/", "_" -replace ":", "|"
$filename += ".xml"
$path = "C:\Temp\$filename"
Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Force -Out $path -PersistBrandingFiles -PersistPublishingFiles
}
```

I get the templates, I can also use them, but the web parts are missing (xml view web parts, content query web parts)

Comment: Do you mean SPSites or SPWebs?

Comment: corrected, SPWeb. I would like to replicate the "Save Site as template" funcionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [PnP PowerShell](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell), namely the Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate, although I have a feeling it doesn't support SPWebs (although [documentation](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Commands/Provisioning/GetProvisioningTemplate.cs) talks of "webs").

So something like:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/publishing" -UseWebLogin

Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Out "C:\Path\to\template.xml" -PersistBrandingFiles -PersistPublishingFiles;
```

Comment: Thanks I will check if this works good for me or not. I was really looking for a way that ends up in the solution gallery and make the templates usable by the end users.

Comment: Looks like working, but this method does not save the web parts on the page. I checked the xml templates, there's no trace in them. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry for the late feedback, this looks promising.

Answer (score 2):

Site Provisioning with PnP PowerShell is good choice :

```
Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Out C:\temp\template.pnp -PersistBrandingFiles 
New-PnPTenantSite -Url 'https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/pnptempate' -Title 'New Site Collection' -Owner 'admin@domain.co.uk'
Connect-PnPOnline 'https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/pnptempate'
Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Path C:\temp\template.pnp
```

Another approach you can use CSOM to meet your requirement .

[Save Site as Template" using JSOM or CSOM](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bca7f30b-ee3e-4128-9eb4-5699d3f88662/save-site-as-template-using-jsom-or-csom?forum=sharepointdevelopment)