# Is there a way to save a site in SharePoint online as a template programmatically (with an API, PowerShell, C#, etc.)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, powershell, sharepoint-rest-api, site-template

I have a SharePoint Online site that has custom scripts enabled, and I want to programmatically save it as a template. I do not want to use PnP Provisioning Templates, I want to access the same functionality as `savetmpl.aspx` but programmatically. I know that in SharePoint Server you can use the `SPWeb.SaveAsTemplate` method in PowerShell or C#, but this is not present in SharePoint Online. Is there a way to do this?

I also found the following url: https://mytenant-admin.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/sites.asmx. I see `ExportWeb` listed there. Would this work in SharePoint Online?

I looked at [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/240204/create-site-template-with-powershell) question, but I do not want to use PnP Provisioning

Comment: Just curious, why don't you want to use PnP Provisioning? It's safer, better supported, and more advanced than site templates ever were. But, I'm sure you have your reasons and I am interested in hearing them.

Comment: I want to back up many sites, but I don't want the regular users who use these sites to have to go through me or connect to powershell on their own in order to activate these backups, especialy when they are already familiar with templates and the solution gallery.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! PnP Provisioning is not a good backup service so that makes sense. It's great for templates though. I don't think you'll have much luck with Site Templates though as these are not supported for publishing sites (classic) or modern sites in SP Online.

Comment: They are not supported, but you can set ``DenyAddAndCustomizePages`` to 0 using PowerShell and then saving a site as template will be enabled.

Comment: Templates are not backups. You should be looking at a proper backup solution. And yes, you can bypass the restriction but it isn't supported for restoration.