# Create a copy of a site collection (modern communication site)

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, modern-experience, administration, pnp

I have a modern communication site collection which I used as the development site collection >> and this site contains 3 lists >> the lists refer to each other using lookup fields.

Now I want to create a copy of the communication site collection to act as the production site. So is there an automated way to do this job?

I only need to copy the site and its lists without the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PnP provisioning engine for such activities in SharePoint online.

You can generate & use **site template** for your requirements.

> The easiest way to create a custom provisioning template is to create a fresh new site collection in SharePoint Online, configure your artifacts (site columns, content types, lists, pages, etc.), and save the result as a provisioning template.

**Source**: [Introducing the PnP provisioning engine](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/introducing-the-pnp-provisioning-engine)

Answer (score 0):

**Please following steps:**

1.First, please enable **Custom Script** in SharePoint Online

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com
Set-SPOSite -Identity https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0
```

2.Create a site template using PnP Site Provisioning

You can use **Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate** to create a site template using PnP Site Provisioning.

```
Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Out C:\template\template.pnp -PersistBrandingFiles 
New-PnPTenantSite -Url 'https://tenantURL/sites/sitename' -Title 'New Site Collection' -Owner 'melqassas@tenanturl'
Connect-PnPOnline 'https://tenantURL/sites/sitename'
Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Path C:\template\template.pnp
```

**Reference:**

- [Create site template with PowerShell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/240204/create-site-template-with-powershell)